# bar code scanner is too slow to read the code

Tags: codenameone

I have used codenameone codescanner library to read bar code. It uses third party scanner which if used separately works fine and is quick to read the bar code. But using codenameone app, the same scanner is too slow(most of the time unable to scan). I have tested it in samsung devices and few other devices. The outcome is not so good. How can I enhance the scanner?

code:

```
 CodeScanner.getInstance().scanBarCode(new ScanResult() {

    public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
        //barCode.setText("Bar: " + contents);
        cnt.addComponent(new Label(contents));
        cnt.revalidate();
    }

    public void scanCanceled() {
        System.out.println("cancelled");
    }

    public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
        System.out.println("err " + message);
    }
});
```

One more thing, some time it reads the bar code but gives different code rather than those written below the code. for eg I was scanning IMEI no of mobile device, it has more than 15-20 numbers, but the scanner gives the 5-6 digit numbers other than those IMEI numbers. What happened here?

you can see the problem in the video...
https://youtu.be/xCtx0ZlFH0U

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the explicit code type you are trying to read e.g.:

Display.getInstance().setProperty("android.scanTypes", "UPC_E");

You can see the list of code types [here](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/blob/master/android-integration/src/main/java/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentIntegrator.java#L125-L140).

Alternatively try the little monkey QR code library (it works with barcodes too) it's often better on Android.

Comment: I tried to test little monkey qr code lib for bar code but it gives build error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082234/littlemonkey-qrscanner-library-build-issue

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5:

If you are using AVFoundation, you should use below metadata object types:

```
  metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39Mod43,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.dataMatrix,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean8,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.face,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.interleaved2of5,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.itf14,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.qr,
        AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce]
```

and you can inform users that they should not bring the camera too close to the barcode. (for EAN barcodes)