# LittleMonkey QRScanner library build issue

Tags: codenameone

I've used littleMonkey QRScanner library but it works in simulator(shows scanner not supported dialog box). But when I build the project it gives build error.

PS: I've deleted all build hints and refresh lib again but still same problem. 
I've kept cn1-codescan.cn1lib and QRScanner.cn1lib as suggested in https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner

My code:

```
   import org.littlemonkey.qrscanner.QRScanner;
   import com.codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult;

    QRScanner.scanQRCode(new ScanResult() {
        public void scanCompleted(String contents, String formatName, byte[] rawBytes) {
            Dialog.show("Completed", contents, "OK", null);
        }

        public void scanCanceled() {
            Dialog.show("Cancelled", "Scan Cancelled", "OK", null);
        }

        public void scanError(int errorCode, String message) {
            Dialog.show("Error", message, "OK", null);
        }
    });
```

Build error:

> When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or
>   version is empty When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either
>   group, name or version is empty When unzipping library
>   ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version is empty When
>   unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version
>   is empty Using incremental javac compilation. Incremental java
>   compilation is an incubating feature. Not using incremental javac
>   compilation. Using incremental javac compilation. Not using
>   incremental javac compilation. Using incremental javac compilation.
>   All projects evaluated. Selected primary task 'assembleDebug' from
>   project : Tasks to be executed: [task ':preBuild', task
>   ':preDebugBuild', task ':checkDebugManifest', task ':preReleaseBuild',
>   task ':prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library', task
>   ':prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus830Library', task
>   ':prepareZBarScannerLibraryLibrary', task ':prepareDebugDependencies',
>   task ':compileDebugAidl', task ':compileDebugRenderscript', task
>   ':generateDebugBuildConfig', task ':mergeDebugShaders', task
>   ':compileDebugShaders', task ':generateDebugAssets', task
>   ':mergeDebugAssets', task ':generateDebugResValues', task
>   ':generateDebugResources', task ':mergeDebugResources', task
>   ':processDebugManifest', task ':processDebugResources', task
>   ':generateDebugSources', task
>   ':incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard', task
>   ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac', task ':compileDebugNdk', task
>   ':compileDebugSources', task ':prePackageMarkerForDebug', task
>   ':transformClassesWithDexForDebug', task ':mergeDebugJniLibFolders',
>   task ':transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug', task
>   ':processDebugJavaRes', task
>   ':transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug', task
>   ':validateDebugSigning', task ':packageDebug', task ':zipalignDebug',
>   task ':assembleDebug'] Creating In-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin:
>   MaxSize{878900} Creating In-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin:
>   MaxSize{6500} Creating In-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin:
>   MaxSize{21900} Creating In-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin:
>   MaxSize{4300} :preBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started.
>   :preBuild Skipping task ':preBuild' as it has no actions. :preBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :preBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took
>   0.006 secs. :preDebugBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started. :preDebugBuild Skipping task ':preDebugBuild' as it has no actions.
>   :preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE :preDebugBuild (Thread[Daemon
>   worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs. :checkDebugManifest
>   (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started. :checkDebugManifest Executing
>   task ':checkDebugManifest' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
>   Task has not declared any outputs. :checkDebugManifest (Thread[Daemon
>   worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs. :preReleaseBuild
>   (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) started. :preReleaseBuild Skipping task
>   ':preReleaseBuild' as it has no actions. :preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :preReleaseBuild (Thread[Daemon worker,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002
>   secs. :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library (Thread[Daemon
>   worker,5,main]) started. :prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library
>   Invalidating in-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin
>   Invalidating in-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin
>   Invalidating in-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin
>   Invalidating in-memory cache of
>   /tmp/build3593943200349845410xxx/Test/.gradle/2.11/taskArtifacts/outputFileStates.bin
>   Executing task ':prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library'
>   (up-to-date check took 0.023 secs) due to:   No history is available.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > Manifest merger failed : Attribute activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity@label
>   >     value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:114-146      is
>   >     also present at [:ZBarScannerLibrary:] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-36
>   >     value=(Scanner).      Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to
>   >      element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:3-149 to override.
> - Try: Run with --debug option to get more log output.
> - Exception is: org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.   at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
>     at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)    at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>     at
>     org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>     at
>     org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)    at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>     at
>     org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>     at
>     org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Manifest merger failed :
>     Attribute
>     activity#com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity@label
>     value=(@string/app_name) from AndroidManifest.xml:25:114-146  is also
>     present at [:ZBarScannerLibrary:] AndroidManifest.xml:18:13-36
>     value=(Scanner).  Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:label"' to
>      element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:3-149 to override.   at
>     com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.mergeManifests(AndroidBuilder.java:686)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.doFullTaskAction(MergeManifests.java:65)
>     at
>     com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:82)
>     at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:244)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:220)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$IncrementalTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:231)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:209)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
>     at
>     org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
>     ... 68 more

update 1: added in codenameone_settings.properties file but still build errors

```
codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android\:name\="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity" android\:screenOrientation\="landscape" android\:label\="@string/app_name" tools\:replace\="android\:label" />
```

New build errors after update1

```
When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version is empty
When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version is empty
When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version is empty
When unzipping library ':ZBarScannerLibrary:, either group, name or version is empty
Using incremental javac compilation.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build3235388660761476489xxx/ScannerTest/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

* Try:
Run with --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot read packageName from /tmp/build3235388660761476489xxx/ScannerTest/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
    at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getPackageFromManifest(VariantConfiguration.java:999)
    at com.android.builder.core.VariantConfiguration.getOriginalApplicationId(VariantConfiguration.java:780)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy:167)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig$ConfigAction$_execute_closure1.doCall(GenerateBuildConfig.groovy)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$2.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:84)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper$MappedPropertyImpl.getValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:136)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.ConventionAwareHelper.getConventionValue(ConventionAwareHelper.java:114)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.GenerateBuildConfig_Decorated.getBuildConfigPackageName(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:458)
    at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:166)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:456)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator.validate(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:277)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:151)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
```

**Update 2: error log about camera permission in marshmallow device samsung J7 prime**

```
02-18 08:35:56.338: E/SamsungIME(25272):          isHWKeyboardConnected() = false --> false
02-18 08:35:56.388: E/Qmage(27688): isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
02-18 08:35:56.388: E/Qmage(27688): isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
02-18 08:35:56.408: E/Qmage(27688): isQIO : stream is not a QIO file
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/CameraService(2255): Permission Denial: can't use the camera pid=1563, uid=10244
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): Process: com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal, PID: 1563
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal/com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4225)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4327)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3426)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.hardware.Camera.<init>(Camera.java:568)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.hardware.Camera.open(Camera.java:423)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActivity.onResume(ZBarScannerActivity.java:75)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1287)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7015)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:4214)
02-18 08:35:56.458: E/AndroidRuntime(1563):     ... 10 more
```

my project properties

[image]

I have a one more question. In older devices it is reading smaller bar code reader but I need to read imei no. of mobile devices. It is a bit large. So it is not reading imei no. Do I have to do anything else to read that?

eg: it is not reading the following imei bar code

[image]

Update 2:

Got the camera permission through native code that triggers the camera permission in marshmallow device but that doesnot solve the camera permission denial issue

NativeImpl file:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((android.app.Activity) Lenovo.getContext(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},0);
```

Comment: Are you importing the right package? What's the error log?

Comment: I have updated the imports & build error above.... import org.littlemonkey.qrscanner.QRScanner; import com.codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult;

Answer (score 1):

I have applied Shai's patch and rebuilt the library.  You'll be able to update the lib in via the Codename One Settings' Extensions section.

This also required a small change to the build server which will released in the next update (this Friday).   I.e. you'll have to wait until Friday to send a build.

Comment: hello steve thanks for the new update.. it works in older devices but it doesnot ask for permission in marshmallow devices and app crashes. I debug it and found out permission denial issue (PS it doesnot ask for camera permission) and the app crashes. I have updated the permission errors above.I have a one more question. In older devices it is reading smaller bar code reader but I need to read imei no. of mobile devices. It is a bit large. So it is not reading imei no. Do I have to do anything else to read that? thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error log it seems that the library broke because of changes from Google. I submitted a pull request to the author of the library which he will hopefully review and incorporate here:

https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/pull/5

You can probably fork the library as a workaround and integrate this fix manually to see if this works around the issue.

Comment: I've added "codename1.arg.android.xapplication=<activity android\:name\="com.dm.zbar.android.scanner.ZBarScannerActiv‌​ity" android\:screenOrientation\="landscape" android\:label\="@string/app_name" tools\:replace\="android\:label" />" in codenameone_settings.properties file but there still is build errors. Have a look at update 1 above.

Comment: That won't work since the library will replace it automatically when you send the build and duplicate the statement making the problem worse.

Comment: what can I do to solve the problem then? My app is based on bar scanner so I need to make sure of the bar reader first...

Comment: For now the workarounds are: a. remove littlemonkey QR reader. b. build it yourself and incorporate the change I added in the pull request.

Comment: hello shai.. I didnt see anything in the pull request... can you please explain it more. Thankyou

Comment: hello shai.. a)I've used other library but it was too slow often gives zero result. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886104/bar-code-scanner-is-too-slow-to-read-the-code b)I didnt see anything in the pull request... can you please explain it more. Moreover how can I build it myself? I'm afraid I didnt get you.  Thankyou

Comment: The pull request has one commit which includes this diff: https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner/pull/5/commits/5ec03e03ef6e7164c4bfb50602c63925f4c4310b scroll to the right to see the difference

Comment: yeahh I added "tools\:replace\="android\:label" in the particular line but that too gave build error, please see my first comment. you told it makes the problem worse. I have given the build error after the update too in the question above

Comment: Did you change it in the lib? Did you delete the andoid.* build hints and refresh libs after making that change?

Comment: yeahh i deleted all the build hints. However I have change that line in codenameone_settings.properties file. Should I do anything in the library? I had the same lib files kept in lib folder.

Comment: You should have changed it within the library like I did in the pull request otherwise the refresh libs with now duplicate the line. Notice that refresh libs is implicitly invoked when you send a build.

Comment: I'm so so sorry I didn't get it. How can I change the library? Should I modify anything in the lib folder. Please elaborate a bit. Desperately want to make the scanner right...

Comment: That library is open source, you can download it apply the patch and compile it

Comment: Ok I think I got it now. I downloaded the library project and made changes on the codenameone_library_appended.properties file but it gives import error (com.codename1.ext.codescan does not exist) while building the library... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42246554/littlemonkey-qrcode-scanner-library-patch-issue-while-generating-cn1lib-library

Comment: Hello shai., thanks for the new update... but there is error in marshmallow devices. It doesnot ask for camera permission and the app crashes. I have updated the error debug log and my build hint img in above question (update 2).I have a one more question. In older devices it is reading smaller bar code reader but I need to read imei no. of mobile devices. It is a bit large. So it is not reading imei no. Do I have to do anything else to read that? thankyou

Comment: That would require deeper digging into the cn1lib code, it should be relatively easy to fix but I don't know if we'll have the time to get into those. See this post about asking for permissions in native code: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/marshmallow-permissions-in-the-simulator-and-native-code.html

Comment: My team kept the android native code in nativeImpl file inside android folder and it ask for camera permission. But that doesnot solve the camera permission issue in bar code scanner. I have updated the native code above.That is abit different from what you've suggested but it worked.Please have a look. Moreover I've tried the way forcing permission natively but it is not working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42323772/forcing-permission-in-marshmallow-devices-codenameone I want to solve it desperately. Please help

Comment: You have several threads here and with support so it's hard for me to follow where you are stuck and properly help.