# Forcing permission in marshmallow devices codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I have created a NativeTest.java

1.code:

```
import com.codename1.system.NativeInterface;

public interface NativeTest extends NativeInterface{
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent();    
}
```

2. generated the native interfaces
3. inside native\android\pathToNativeiImpl

NativeTestImpl.java code:

```
public class NativeTestImpl {
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        if(!com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, "App requires camera permission for scanner")){
         // you didn't get the permission, you might want to return here

            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
      }


    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

native\javase\com\lenovo\capitaleyenepal\NativeTestImpl.java

```
public class NativeTestImpl implements com.lenovo.capitaleyenepal.NativeTest{
    public boolean isSupported() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    }


}
```

Still it is not forcing the permission, how can I force the permission for using camera?

Build error after adding native code:

```
    Compiling with source level 1.7 and target level 1.7.
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
file or directory '/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/debug/java', not found
Compiling with JDK Java compiler API.
/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/main/java/com/lenovo/capitaleyenepal/NativeTestImpl.java:8: error: package Manifest does not exist
        if(!com.codename1.impl.android.AndroidNativeUtil.checkForPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, "App requires camera permission for scanner")){
                                                                                    ^
/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/main/java/com/lenovo/capitaleyenepal/NativeTestImpl.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class NativeTestImpl
/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/main/java/com/lenovo/capitaleyenepal/NativeTestImpl.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                           ^
  symbol:   class Intent
  location: class NativeTestImpl
/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/main/java/com/lenovo/capitaleyenepal/NativeTestImpl.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable MediaStore
  location: class NativeTestImpl
/tmp/build8873426072869291288xxx/Lenovo/src/main/java/com/lenovo/capitaleyenepal/NativeTestImpl.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                                                  ^
  symbol:   method getPackageManager()
  location: class NativeTestImpl
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Comment: Where is the native method declaration? You need to have methods in the native test otherwise what do you invoke?

Comment: Sorry I have added the method but it gives build error. Is it the right way to do that? Please have a look. I've never implemented native code in cn1 so can you make the code right please, if I have done anything wrong? Thankyou. The build error is also updated above after adding the methods.

Comment: You left the line that says 11 errors but removed all the lines above it which detail the exact syntax errors you should have fixed.

Comment: You need to fix your imports. I suggest commenting out your code and building with "include source" then editing it in Android Studio and debugging there.