# Littlemonkey QRcode scanner library patch issue while generating cn1lib library

Tags: codenameone

I downloaded QRScanner project from https://github.com/littlemonkeyltd/QRScanner
and replace "codename1.arg.android.xapplication=" line in codenameone_library_appended.properties file. While building the library, it gives following error.

```
E:\QRScanner-master\src\org\littlemonkey\qrscanner\QRScanner.java:27Stubbing 
Class: E:\QRScanner-master\build\stubs\org/littlemonkey/qrscanner/NativeScanner.java
: error: package com.codename1.ext.codescan does not exist
6 warnings
import com.codename1.ext.codescan.CodeScanner;
E:\QRScanner-master\src\org\littlemonkey\qrscanner\QRScanner.java:28: error: package com.codename1.ext.codescan does not exist
import com.codename1.ext.codescan.ScanResult;
```

**Update 1:** I have added the cn1-codescan.cn1lib dependencies but same problem as above exists...

-Unzipped cn1-codescan.cn1lib and kept main.zip inside lib folder

-changes in build.xml

```
<target name="-pre-compile">
    <echo>Compile is forcing compliance to the supported API's/features for maximum device compatibility. This allows smaller
    code size and wider device support</echo>
    <mkdir dir="build/tmp"/>
    <javac destdir="build/tmp"
        source="1.5"
        target="1.5"
        bootclasspath="lib/CLDC11.jar"
        classpath="lib/main.zip:${javac.classpath}:${build.classes.dir}">
        <src path="${src.dir}"/>
    </javac>        
</target>
```

nbproject/project.properties file:

```
javac.classpath=\
${file.reference.CLDC11.jar}:\
${file.reference.CodenameOne.jar}:\
${file.reference.CodenameOne_SRC.zip}:\
${file.reference.QRScanner-override}:\
${file.reference.main.zip}
file.reference.main.zip=lib/main.zip
# Space-separated list of extra javac options
```

You can view the project here to see if I had done anything wrong:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ATnICIY2S8VzN0cGpwUTJLZTg

Thankyou

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Hello Diamond...there is a build issue in littlemonkey qrcode issue. Shai told me that it was caused by google. So some line should be changed in library. So I am trying to change the line in a file and regenerate the cn1 lib file. This is the main issue in the barcode library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42082234/littlemonkey-qrscanner-library-build-issue

Answer (score 1):

Fork and download CodeScanner from [here](https://github.com/codenameone/cn1-codescan) and include the relevant package in your project.

Comment: Thanks but I had used this library previously but it often doesnot read the bar code. Shai informed me this lib is a bit buggy in android so I want to use little monkey lib which I was told is pretty good for reading bar code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41886104/bar-code-scanner-is-too-slow-to-read-the-code

Comment: QRScanner was made mainly for Android and it only uses CodeSanner as a fallback for iOS and other platforms.

Comment: I need to scan barcode, not QRcode. And shai told me that little monkey lib does read barcode pretty good. The other one you referred takes too much time to read bar code, often doesnot read it ( PS I havenot tried it to read QR code & I dont need QR codes too)

Comment: Both can read QR and Barcodes. When you use the littleMonkey library, it will scan both QR and Barcodes using QRscanner on Android which is fast and uses CodeScanner on other platforms, which is also fast.

Comment: This question is for solving the build error of little monkey library

Comment: I think the solution is to add the codescan jar to the classpath see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-nest-cn1libs-cross-dependencies.html I'm not sure which approach was used by the author of that lib to implement the dependencies but copying the source probably wasn't the option used.

Comment: I have applied all the changes but the same error exists. Please have a look at update 1 above. Whole lib project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8ATnICIY2S8VzN0cGpwUTJLZTg